# Calculate fair score for a memory game

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I'm working on a memory game and I would like to include a fair score system.

The data I can use to calculate the score are:

- the number of cards played (6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 30 or 36)
- the number of flips used to finish the game
- the time used to finish the game in seconds

The rules for calculating the score are as follows:

- the more cards used the higher the score
- the less flips needed the higher the score
- the less seconds used the higher the score

The calculation should be progressive in some way. Knocking of 1 flip from 20 flips should be rewarded more than knocking off 1 flip from 50 flips. And knocking of 3 seconds from 60 seconds should be rewarded more than knocking off 3 seconds from 65 seconds.

I tried the following:

For the number of cards: 5 points per card used, so for 8 cards 40 points; for 20 cards 100 points, for 36 cards 180 points.

For the number of flips: 500 points divided by the number of flips used, so for 20 flips 25 points, for 10 flips 50 points.

For the seconds used: 5000 points divided by the number of seconds used, so for 100 seconds 50 points, for 25 seconds 200 points.

Formula: (5 * number of cards) + (500 / flips used) + (5000 / seconds used)

But this calculation is not progressive. I need some kind of factor to multiply the different score elements with so a drop of 5 seconds from 50 weighs more than a drop of 5 seconds from 80. But I cant figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There are lots and lots of possibilities.  You should give us a bunch of sample results and what you would like to the scores to be, so w can give you suggestions.

Comment: Your last paragraph does not seem to be correct:  a drop of $5$ seconds from $50$ yields a gain of $11+$ points, whereas a drop of $5$ seconds from $80$ yields only $4+$ points.  Isn't that exactly what you want?